# How to adjust length of my bicycle kickstand?

Tags: adjustment, kickstand

I have a bike kickstand and would like to adjust its length. With its current length the bike is easy to fall over, onto the side of the kickstand. Unfortunately I have not figured out how to lengthen the kickstand. Please have a look at the attached pictures and give some instructions if you can. The kickstand has been attached by a bike shop and I have no clue what model it is. Unfortunately I cannot go back to the shop and ask, as it is now rather far to go there.

[image: bike stand]
[image: bike stand back side]

Comment: Aside - are you pushing the handlebars toward the side with the stand, or away, when parking?  That alone can make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by spraying some penetrating oil on that rusty bolt in the second picture.   This will help with turning the bolt while not stripping it or munching the head.   Leave it for 5 mins to soak in.

Then use a suitable hex driver that is a good fit on the 6-sided socket visible.  You might need to clean out any embedded dirt to get the tool to seat well.   I suspect its a 4mm fitting, but could be 5mm or small chance it is imperial.

Once it is loose, you should be able to drop the lower part of the kickstand down some, then tighten and test.  That little silver coloured part above the screw is likely a latch with a spring - you may need to press or lift it to move the lower part.

I don't know if there's a positive stop inside, or if you could slide the foot-part all the way off by accident.

If you're already fully extended, the only other option is to put extra thickness under the foot, by perhaps gluing or screwing a small block.   You may not need a lot - 5mm under the foot will move the handlebars over by 4x that distance.  Test with various thicknesses before committing.

I would not recommend sliding the kickstand forward on your chainstay - the material that the stay is made from often gets thinner away from the welded ends, and is also less-supported, so you can damage your frame.   Stays are often like a butted spoke, so it can definitely be thinner in the middle.  
Additionally, the rotational (twist) load on the stay is less supported if its clamped further away from the ends.  
  At the same time the external dimension is wider, which allows anything clamped on to slide toward the narrower section and become loose (potentially swinging into spokes)  I had a trailer-clamp that migrated down to the thinner part of the stay.

The final option is to choose a kickstand that has a longer leg.  You can get models that mount just behind the bottom bracket, which is more stable due to being near the center of the bike.   You can also get two-legged stands which raise one wheel off the ground but give you a positive 3-legged triangle for stability on the flat.

Comment: The latch with the spring would not move until hit by hammer. Even then, it did not move enough and I could not change the length. Now trying to glue something below the stand.

Comment: @laolux sounds like corrosion.  Add penetrating oil and some gentle heat via hot air to help free up the latch part.  If you heat with flame, it risks igniting oil, or otherwise damaging things.